# How to POST / PUT webhook from Google Sheets when new rows are added

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, webhooks

Disclaimer : I'm a newbie and doesn't know much. I understand webhooks a little bit, but doesn't know how to code.

### Now that is out of the way, what I'm trying to do is, send data from a CRM to google sheets, do some calculations and send it back. I was able to figure out the first step of sending from CRM and doing the calculations.

Here is what I want to do..

I'd like to be able to send the updated data from googlesheet back to the CRM as a webhook when a new row is added to the google sheets.

So I have created a google sheet, I was able to add a trigger to run myFunction on Edit. My current myFunction code is at the end.

**Ideally it should send "id" and "updated_value" fetched from google sheets to the CRM via webhook (PUT method) as it will be updating a contact record.

Can anyone please share the code to add here or guide me how to write one? Thank you in advance**

This is my code so far and I'm currently finding resources to learn to add more lines to it

Update: One problem I'm facing now is that, I'm getting the 1000th row as the last row as "I've used array function in one column. So I'm not actually getting the non-empty last row.

```html
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, lastColumn);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var data = {
    "id": values[0][1],
    "f2130": values[0][3]
  };
  var options = {
    'method': 'PUT',
    'url': 'https://api.ontraport.com/1/Contacts',
    'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Api-Appid': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6',
      'Api-Key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxH'

    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
       "f2130": f2130,
      "id": id
    })

  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.ontraport.com/1/Contacts", options);
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your question, I thought that there might be several questions in your question. So, unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your actual question?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike Sorry if my question was confusing. I am trying to send a webhook from google sheets when a new row is added. This webhook should send ID and updated_data to the CRM via webhook

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood your question as `I am trying to send a webhook from google sheets when a new row is added.`. In this case, it is required to know the method for adding the new row. By this, I think that the direction of modification will be known. So, can I ask you about the detail of it? By the way, your showing script works fine, and you want the method for executing your script when the new row is added. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike thank you for your reply and sorry for the delayed response. After some trial and error I have figured it out myself. I've added the code in the thread. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I finally able to figure it out by myself. Here is the code

Also you can read the steps here
https://damartech.com/how-to-send-and-receive-data-from-ontraport-to-google-sheet-and-back-without-zapier/

```html
function opUpdater() {

  // Replace `spreadsheetId` and `sheetName` with the ID and name of your Google Sheets document
  const spreadsheetId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  const sheetName = "xxxxxx";

  // Get the sheet by ID and name
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // Get the number of rows in the sheet
  const numRows = sheet.getLastRow();

 
  // Initialize a variable to store the index of the last non-empty row
  let lastNonEmptyRowIndex = 0;

  // Loop through each row in the sheet
  for (let i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {

    // Get the values in the current row
    const rowValues = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

    // Check if the row is empty
    if (rowValues.every(cell => cell === "")) {
      // If the row is not empty, store its index as the last non-empty row
      lastNonEmptyRowIndex = i-1;
      break;
    }
  }

  // If a non-empty row was found, get its values
  if (lastNonEmptyRowIndex > 0) {
    const lastNonEmptyRowValues = sheet.getRange(lastNonEmptyRowIndex, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

    // Define the variables that will be used in the request
    // You can find the values from google sheet column number-1
    var contact_id = parseInt(lastNonEmptyRowValues[1]);
    var new_date = lastNonEmptyRowValues[3];
    
  }


  // Define the URL for the request
  let url = "https://api.ontraport.com/1/Contacts";

  // Define the options for the request
var options = {
  "method": "put",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Api-Appid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Api-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "payload": JSON.stringify({
    "id": contact_id,
    "f2130": new_date    
  }),
  "muteHttpExceptions": true
};

try {
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
const responseBody = response.getContentText();
const data = JSON.parse(responseBody);

Logger.log(data.data.attrs.id);
Logger.log(data.data.attrs.f2130);


} catch (error) {
  Logger.log(error.message);
  Logger.log(error.response);
}

}
```